# Can I still install and OS after I chose to to encrypt LVM mt drive?

Tags: server, system-installation

I am installing Ubuntu Server's latest update and am wondering, if I don't like it or want to change to a different OS, can I do that even though I chose to encrypt my drive during the "Partition during LVM" segment of installation?